# Trying to use my UIViewController from UIkit in SwiftUI causes Protocol to not confirm to the representable

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, metal

I am learning and making a simple app with graphics API metal and I am trying to make my view controller from UIKit display in SwiftUI. I have tried to make UIViewControllerRepresentable out of my ViewController class but that keeps resulting in the error of Type 'UIViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerRepresentable'. This most likely because my ViewController is now throwing an error of Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'UIViewController' so it does not have a protocol. So how do I make the ViewController which contains all my metal code adopt the protocol that the representable needs?

here is my code:

```
//ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    UIViewController()
  } 
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
     ContentView()
   }
}

//UIViewController.swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct UIViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable { //error: Type 'UIViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerRepresentable'
   func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController{
      return ViewController()
   }
}

struct UIViewController_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
      UIViewController()
  }
}

//ViewController.swift
import UIKit
import Metal

class ViewController: UIViewController { //error: Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'UIViewController'
  var device: MTLDevice!
  var metalLayer: CAMetalLayer!

//created is the buffer to send the points over to gpu
var vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer!

//starts the render pipeline
var pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!

//command queue
var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!

//timer to render the screen frame by frame
var timer: CADisplayLink!

//insuring the view is loaded so the device can actually be used
override func viewDidLoad() { //error: Method does not override any method from its superclass
  super.viewDidLoad()
    
  device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    
  metalLayer = CAMetalLayer()
  metalLayer.device = device
  metalLayer.pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
  metalLayer.framebufferOnly = true
  metalLayer.frame = view.layer.frame
  view.layer.addSublayer(metalLayer) //error: Use of unresolved identifier 'view'
  ....
```

There was no errors in ViewController until I tried to display it in my SwiftUI.

Sorry for being a complete beginner at IOS development and graphics but thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the error

> Type 'UIViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerRepresentable'

I guess you're missing the method *[updateUIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable/updateuiviewcontroller(_:context:))* from the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` protocol

Also, calling your struct `UIViewController` *might* cause some name conflict

Comment: ok I added renamed it to ViewControllerRep and added the  ```func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: Self.UIViewControllerType, context: Self.Context){}``` into the struct resulting in the error ```Reference to invalid associated type 'UIViewControllerType' of type 'ViewControllerRep'```. so I changed it to ```func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Self.Context){}``` which gave no errors but I still have the error ```Type 'UIViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerRepresentable'``` from the first line of the struct

Comment: alright I deleted my UIViewController and Unlinked it and then made sure ViewController inherited from the official UIViewController and it worked perfectly with the update statement. Thanks for help the help and yeah I should work on a better naming scheme

Answer (score 0):

implement the two protocol methods in UIViewControllerRepresentable : makeUIViewController and updateUIViewController. Then in the second, make sure to cast your controller to UIPageViewController if you want to use it (or other class you want). Like this:

```
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: Self.UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
    guard let pageViewController = uiViewController as? UIPageViewController else { return }
    let myControllers = [UIViewController(), UIViewController()] // example
    pageViewController.setViewControllers(myControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true)
}
```